# Mesos task resources - CPU & Mem

Tags: mesos, mesos-chronos

I use Meosos for batch Jobs. Jobs will be running as a docker container by the framework. The are 2 salves running on each VM. The resource for each Job was set to

```
CPUS - 0.1
MEM - 1G
```

Its a 4 core machine and mesos was considering it as 8 core as there are 2 slaves in each VM. So, it tried to overload the VM by submitting too many tasks, literally up to 80 jobs ( (4+4)/0.1 = 80). So, during the peak load VM used to crash.

Tried changing the CPU to 0.5 so that the VM will not be overloaded. (( (4+4)/0.5 = 20)). But, looks like CPU usage still goes up to 95%. The tasks are not CPU intensive task, but not sure why it is trying to consume 95%.

Is it like, tasks will be using the resource no matter even it actually requires them? So, it will allocate 0.5 by default or max to 0.5 in case it requires?

Comment: https://zcox.wordpress.com/2014/09/17/cpu-resources-in-docker-mesos-and-marathon/. Looks like i may need to increase the CPU to 1.0 from 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having two agents on the same host/VM is more like an antipattern. If you want to oversubscribe on resources, have a look at the Mesos docs at http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/oversubscription/